# Trying to understand the use of useCallback in this situation with React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I'm trying to learn why it's necessary to use `useCallback` in this situation:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const navigation = useContext(NavigationContext);

  const redirect = useCallback(() => {
    navigation.navigate("Home");
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    redirect();
  }, [redirect]);
}
```

I can't use `navigation` directly inside `useEffect()` and also I can't refer the function without `useCallback()`. I don't know why I can use other objects like Firebase Context (from a Firestore instance) without any problem inside useEffect, but I can't use `navigation` directly.

Comment: While your question is valid, why not using `useNavigation` from `react-navigation-hooks`

Comment: @ilkerkaran the project is very large and I'm still using the v4 with context. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Maybe the other context objects are returned memoized already?

Comment: @DespinaKastani yes I know the hook alternative that is also available for v4 with `react-navigation-hooks`. But in this particular case, what is provoking that `NavigationContext` depends on `useCallback()`?

Comment: @DespinaKastani about your edited comment, I'm just using the `React.createContext()` with the other objects. I don't know if React "pre-memoizes" using that function.

Comment: This is interesting.  When you say you "can't" do it the other two ways, what is it that happens?  I actually get a typescript error on your code due to calling `useCallback` with no dependencies, as that means it gets re-created on each render and it pointless.

Comment: `useEffect(() => { navigation.navigate("Home"); }, [navigation]);` looks fine at compile-time, as does `const redirect = () => { navigation.navigate("Home"); };  useEffect(() => {  redirect();  }, [redirect]);`.  Is is a run-time problem?  Or an environment problem?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look in the equivalent codebases:
[Firebase Context provider](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-firebase/blob/master/modules/database/src/Context.ts) is returned memoized
whilst the [react-navigation one](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/NavigationContext.tsx) just returns the object.